# how do I access data when title is in number format in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am accessing data from an excel sheet and the table header is in number format (eg:2005-06) as below:

[image]

I want to access the data but I am getting an error while I try to access using objects.
This is my console which is showing the fetched data:

[image]

This is the code I have written and getting an error:

[image]

How should I access this data? Note: I cannot change the names of the fields.

Comment: Use square brackets and quotes

Comment: @DanielA.White can you give an example?

Comment: As daniel said d['2011-12'] that is the correct way. However I recommend you to map the excel to a structure that makes you easy to access.

Answer (score 0):

use `d['2004-05']`
you can check about object key accessors here more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 0):

Because the key contains `-`, you need to use key accessors.

For example

```
d["2004-05"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
<td>{d.['2004-05']}</td>
<td>{d.['2005-06']}</td>
<td>{d.['2006-07']}</td>
<td>{d.['2007-08']}</td>
<td>{d.['2009-10']}</td>
<td>{d.['2010-11']}</td>
<td>{d.['2011-12']}</td>
```